# iBeacon Android Service possible?

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I was wondering if somebody could explain to me if it's possible to a service with the raduis networks android SDK? So I want to make it so it's running in the background when a user presses a button to start the service and then once the user detects the data packet it add's uuid, major, minor and proxid into a database. I would like to know how to do the service bit as I assume it's part of the SDK.

Sam

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do this, and you do not even need an additional service. The Android iBeacon Library already runs as a service, and it can continue executing in the background simply by binding it to your own extended version of `android.app.Application`, which would be responsible for starting ranging for iBeacons.  For your use case, you would insert the identifiers of each iBeacon into the database in the `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` method.

If you only want the service to start when the user presses a button, simply call a method in your `android.app.Application` class to start ranging from your `android.app.Activity` class that hosts the button.

You can see the basic setup from the code examples [here.](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/samples.html)

You can do all of this with the open source library, but the [Pro version](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/pro/download.html) provides additional tools that make it easier to run the service in the background and limit battery usage.